# Using getElementsByTagName in vba returns runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, runtime-error, getelementsbyclassname

Imagine the following HTML:

```
            <div class="result-row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-5 result-score-padding">
                        <div class="result-score" align="right">Portugal</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 result-score-padding" align="center">
                        <div class="result-score">2 - 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 result-score-padding">
                        <div class="result-score">Spain</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the code below, i'm using getElementsByClassName in VBA to get innerText from elements:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Integer
Dim game As String

IE.navigate "https://www.example.com"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
Set doc = IE.document
For i=0 To 2
    game = Trim(doc.getElementsByClassName("result-score")(i).innerText)
Next i
```

However, this code doesn't return the desired outcome as it returns runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

I want to extract "Portugal 2 - 2 Spain"

The url is http://www.stoiximan.gr/virtuals/

Comment: `example.com` does not have `Portugal 2 - 2 Spain`.

Comment: You should be able to return Portugal, 2-2, Spain. Is there an actual URL to share?

Comment: @Vityata it's not the actual url. the actual url is http://www.stoiximan.gr/virtuals/

Comment: I coouldn't find `Portugal 2 - 2 Spain` in that page using the url you have provided in the comment. Try to be more specific about how to populate/find that output manually @Spyros Psa. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM the the names of the team change all the time it was just an example, the struct of the url is always the same the name of the teams change and the score.

Comment: If you show more HTML it may be that there is a parent frame/iframe to deal with or you may simply need a longer wait before trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You *overwrite* your "game" variable.

Then you lose the previous contents.

Comment: The problem is not the overwiting for the first time my code reaches the game variable it returns "runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set"